# Connect two LANs without NAT in linux

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a PC with address 192.168.3.2. It's connected to a router 192.168.3.1.
Router 192.168.3.1 is connected to another LAN with static address 192.168.88.6
Router at 192.168.8.1 provides an internet access for both 192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.88.0/24
There's also a server 192.168.88.51

I want 192.168.3.2 to have access to 192.168.88.51 without NAT. The main reason -- I need to see client IPs from 192.168.3.0/24, not their SNATted address 192.168.88.6

```
3.2 -> 3.1/88.6 -> 88.1 -> internet
                    ^
                    |
                  88.51
```

**With NAT:**

192.168.3.0/24 can access 192.168.88.0/24 (and internet) via its default route

Everything works if I have SNAT at 192.168.3.1: `-A POSTROUTING -o wan -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.88.6`

**Without NAT:**

192.168.3.0/24 can still access 192.168.88.0/24 (and internet) via its default route

For router at 192.168.88.1 I added static route to 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.88.6

I removed SNAT rule for 192.168.3.0/24 -> 192.168.88.0/24 (and I still have internet access)

But it does not work, because 192.168.88.1 has rule, that DROPs INVALID (ctstate) packets in FORWARD chain

If I add a rule like `-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID` (or without conntrack at all) before that rule, everything works, but I don't like that

Other rules in FORWARD chain:

```
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o ens18 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT # internet access
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

On 192.168.3.1, I didn't modified FORWARD chain at all. It has only `br0 -> wan` rule. So 192.168.3.1 marks these packets as RELATED/ESTABLISHED? And happily FORWARDs back?

Logged packet: `IN=br0 OUT=br0 MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.88.51 DST=192.168.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=xxxx DPT=57416 WINDOW=65160 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0`

So I have a question:

- why packets are marked as INVALID? Internet access works for 192.168.3.0/24, so packets WAN interface on 192.168.88.1 are tracked properly
- why is there FORWARD between same interface (br0), but different LANs?
- anything else I need to know/check/debug?

**update**

I finally got, that request goes directly from 192.168.3.1 to 192.168.88.51 skipping 192.168.88.1, since it belongs to the same subnet via 192.168.88.6 address

But reply goes through 192.168.88.1, since 192.168.88.51 has no route to 192.168.3.0/24 and should use router 192.168.88.1

What is correct way to fix it? Assigning 192.168.88.6/32 to 192.168.3.1 router makes 192.168.88.0/24 inaccessable at all

Make a separate LAN for just the routers?

Answer (score 2):

If your `192.168.88.0/24` subnet is all bridged together, you shouldn't need forwarding at all, just tell `192.168.88.51` that it can access `192.168.3.0/24` via `192.168.88.6`

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.88.6
```

And the devices on `192.168.3.0/24` will be able to route back via the default route, as you've said.

If you want to stick with letting `192.168.88.51` use its default route, you just need to bypass the rule dropping packets, which should be possible with `-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT`